# Percona Server & MySQL server on the same server on different ports

Tags: mysql, percona

I have MySQL installed from ports, running and listening on port 3306.
On the same server I have Percona Server compiled from sources, running and listening on port 3307.

Here are the process list for percona & mysql:

```
#mysql 
processes bin/sh /usr/local/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-extra-file=/var/db/mysql/my.cnf --user=mysql --datadir=/var/db/mysql --pid-file=/var/db/mysql/mysql.pid
/usr/local/libexec/mysqld --defaults-extra-file=/var/db/mysql/my.cnf --basedir=/usr/local --datadir=/var/db/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/db/mysql/mysql.err --pid-file=/var/db/mysql/mysql.pid

#percona processes
/bin/sh /usr/local/percona/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-extra-file=/home/percona/my.cnf --user=percona --datadir=/home/percona --pid-file=/home/percona/mysql.pid
/usr/local/percona/bin/mysqld --defaults-extra-file=/home/percona/my.cnf --basedir=/usr/local/percona --datadir=/home/percona --plugin-dir=/usr/local/percona/lib/plugin --user=percona --log-error=/home/percona/mysql-error.log --open-files-limit=65535 --pid-file=/home/percona/mysql.pid --socket=/tmp/percona.sock --port=3307
```

As you can see percona is running with `--socket=/tmp/percona.sock --port=3307`.

When I'm trying to connect Percona from localhost, I'm facing strange situation.

```
mysql -S /tmp/percona.sock -uroot -p # ok, I'm connected to Percona
mysql -P 3307 -uroot -p              # NO! I'm connected to MySQL
```

BUT, when I'm trying to connect to 3307 from another server - I'm successfully connected to Percona (not MySQL)

```
#on another server
mysql -P 3307 -h somehost -u root -p # ok, I'm connected to Percona
```

Why? Why connection to 3307 from localhost leads to regular MySQL. But connection to 3307 from another host leads to Percona Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql -P 3307 -uroot -p              # NO! I'm connected to MySQL`, - host by default is `localhost`. If so, a client connects over unix socket, not over TCP. Thus -P option doesn't make sense.
However if you connect like this `mysql -P 3307 -uroot -p  -h 127.0.0.1` it will force the client use TCP and you'll get to Percona.

Comment: Thank you! More info at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712307/mysql-localhost-127-0-0-1